# Text File Format is not saved properly as per saved data format in text file ( Window Form )

Tags: c#

I tried to save the selected ordered item from listbox to a list text file.

In the text file , the string is saved with only column index but not row index.

Here is my code;

```
List<string> TransactionList = new List<string>();

TransactionList.Add(TransactionNumber);
TransactionList.Add(CurrentDate.ToString());
TransactionList.Add(TotalAmount.ToString());

//Looping and add the items from listbox
for (int i = 0; i < ItemSelectedlistBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TransactionList.Add(ItemSelectedlistBox.Items[i].ToString());
}

outputFile.Write(String.Join(SEPARATOR.ToString(), TransactionList.ToArray()));
outputFile.Close();
```

It should be as the following ;

Transaction Number , Date , ItemName , Size , Qty , TotalAmount

Transaction Number , Date , ItemName , Size , Qty , TotalAmount

Comment: You might want to research the notion of *serializing* your data

Comment: So you actually want to create a csv file?

Comment: There's no need to call `ToArray()` on `TransactionList` when writing it to a file.

Comment: While there are plenty information on "Write CSV with C#" (which code tries to do) I don't think that it is actually the problem you have... It looks like you expect `ItemSelectedlistBox.Items` to contain something specific, but clearly it does not match your expectations. Could you please clarify what you've added to `Items` and what you got? I'd recommend to re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code before making the [edit] (consider removing all traces of file operations unless the data in TransactionList actually matches your expectations... Also re-read C# coding guidelines for naming)

Comment: Maybe it’s just me but no idea what this means `the string is saved with only column index but not row index.`

Comment: Lucky guess would be call `TransactionList.Add(Environment.NewLine);` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for your suggestion. I am only a beginner for this program. I save the ItemSelectedListBox.Items into text file and below is outcome.(78058,11/26/2022 1:30:04 AM,0,ChedderBal                         S                  €1.25                      1                 €1.25,PumpkingBal                        R                  €3.15                      1                 €3.15,SeasameBal                         R                  €3.15                      1                 €3.15 )

Comment: @RandRandom Sorry for my bad explanation. All the items in the listbox , only saved in one row in text file instead of many rows as per the listbox format.

Comment: @itsuki Would you edit your question and add that there with the proper formatting? It's difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky guess answer

```
StringBuilder sb = new();

for (int i = 0; i < ItemSelectedlistBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //if you need an header you can use this code
    if (i == 0)
    {
       sb.Append("Transaction Number");
       sb.Append(",");
       sb.Append("Date");
       sb.Append(",");
       sb.Append("ItemName");
       sb.Append(",");
       sb.Append("Size");
       sb.Append(",");
       sb.Append("Qty");
       sb.Append(",");
       sb.Append("TotalAmount");
       sb.AppendLine();
    }

    sb.Append(TransactionNumber);
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(CurrentDate.ToString());
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(ItemSelectedlistBox.Items[i].ToString());
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(TotalAmount.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine();
}

outputFile.Write(sb.ToString());
outputFile.Close();
```

Since you said the output should be

```
Transaction Number , Date , ItemName , Size , Qty , TotalAmount
Transaction Number , Date , ItemName , Size , Qty , TotalAmount
```

So each line containing `Transaction Number` I have moved all the values inside the loop.

To separate the values per „row“ I am adding a line break - `sb.AppendLine();` - inside the loop.

I am using the `StringBulder` class instead of a list of strings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder

**Notice:**

This code assumes that this line of code

```
sb.Append(ItemSelectedlistBox.Items[i].ToString());
```

will output the desired values `ItemName , Size , Qty` if that isn’t the case you would need to explain how to get those values.